# How to use variables from exported constants in other files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, constants

I have this exported `const` in one file `useLocation.tsx` where I get the user's location and retrieve the user's county, state/province, and country. I also have an exported `const` in another file `useCountryData.tsx` where I fetch the COVID cases and deaths from an API. There is a variable in `useLocation.tsx` that is called `countryNameshort`. How do I use this variable in `useCountryData.tsx`?

**useLocation.tsx**

```
export const useLocation = () => {  
  
    var [stateName, setstateName] = useState(String);
    var [countyName, setCountyName] = useState(String);
    var [countryName, setCountryName] = useState(String);
    var [stateNameshort, setstateNameshort] = useState(String);
    var [countryNameshort, setCountryNameshort] = useState(String);
  
  
  
    const [latitude, setlatitude] = useState(Number);
    const [longitude, setlongitude] = useState(Number);
  
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(Object);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(String);
      
    useEffect(() => {
          (async () => {
            if (Platform.OS === "android" && !Constants.isDevice) {
              setErrorMsg(
                "Oops, this will not work on Snack in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!"
              );
              return;
            }
            let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
            if (status !== "granted") {
              setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
              return;
            }
      
            let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
            setLocation(location);
      
            const latitude = location.coords.latitude;
            setlatitude(latitude);
            const longitude = location.coords.longitude;
            setlongitude(longitude);
          })();
        }, []);
      
        let text = "Waiting..";
        if (errorMsg) {
          text = errorMsg;
        } else if (location) {
          text = JSON.stringify(location);
        }
      
    fetch(
          "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
            latitude +
            "," +
            longitude +
            "&key=" +
            apiKey
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            const resState = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
              (x: any) =>
                x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "administrative_area_level_1")
                  .length > 0
            )[0].long_name;
            setstateName(resState);
            const resCounty = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
              (x: any) =>
                x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "administrative_area_level_2")
                  .length > 0
            )[0].long_name;
            setCountyName(resCounty);
            const resCountry = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
              (x: any) => x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "country").length > 0
            )[0].long_name;
            setCountryName(resCountry);
            const resStateShort = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
              (x: any) =>
                x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "administrative_area_level_1")
                  .length > 0
            )[0].short_name;
            setstateNameshort(resStateShort);
            const resCountryShort = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
              (x: any) => x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "country").length > 0
            )[0].short_name;
            setCountryNameshort(resCountryShort);
            if (countryNameshort === "US") {
              countryNameshort = "US" + "A";
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });

        return { countryName, countyName, stateName, stateNameshort, countryNameshort };
      };
```

**useCountryData.tsx**

```
import { useLocation } from './useLocation';

export const useCountryData = () => {
  const [earliest2, setEarliest2] = useState([]);
  const [countryDeaths, setcountryDeaths] = useState(Number);
  const [countryCases, setcountryCases] = useState(Number);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries")
      .then((response) => {
        setEarliest2(response.data);

        const countryArray = response.data.filter(
          (item) => item.country === props.countryNameshort //???
        );

        const resCountryDeaths = countryArray[0].deaths;
        setcountryDeaths(resCountryDeaths);

        const resCountryCases = countryArray[0].cases;
        setcountryCases(resCountryCases);
        console.log("hiiii", countryCases);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return { countryCases, countryDeaths };
};
```

**CountryCard.tsx**

```
const CountryCard = (props) => {
  const mappedLocation = useMappedLocation();
  const countryName = mappedLocation.country;

  return (
    <RectButton style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: "white" }]}>
      <Text style={[styles.textLocation, { top: 15, left: 10 }]}>
        {countryName} /???
      </Text>
)
}
```

Comment: you do not need to use `.tsx` since you dont make use of tsx expressions (using "html code" in your typescript / javascript). Generally, If you want to use exported constants you need to import them in your file `import { myConst } from 'myFile'`

Comment: This looks like you've used React code and patterns when you're not doing any actual React DOM manipulation. Consequently everything is more confused than it needs to be. The tasks you are performing are simple async operations, possibly leading to the assignment of const values which are promises. These promise values can then be exported and awaited wherever you care about consuming that particular value when it eventually resolves. Learn about await and async and work towards removing every reference to useEffect and useState in your code. They are redundant and creating the problem.

Comment: @messerbill I am actually using react-native typescript for mobile development. I don't get what you mean by not using `.tsx.` I was already importing the constants, but I don't know if I'm passing `countryNameshort` correctly. I have updated the code above.

Comment: @cefn Do I need to use React DOM for mobile development? I just want to know how I can use the `countryNameshort` in `useLocation.tsx` in `useCountryData.tsx`, perhaps using React props.

Comment: I'd recommend to read more about the differences between `javascript` and `typescript` and when to use `jsx` or `tsx`. https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html cheers

Comment: Agreed any UI elements will use a UI framework. Normally the async operations can be well-formed without mixing with React constructs. When your UI needs to consume the result you'd have a single, simple bridge from the UI to the async. So my intuition is that all of these operations should be async calls to get results, and probably sync mappings of those results (extracting bits from the retrieved results) to construct ordinary values as variables. Then finally in your UI code you'll invoke that async code in one call from a single useEffect (possibly in a hook you wrote setting one state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pseudo-code suggestion for how you could refactor these stages, without adopting useEffect and useState for operations that are more conventionally just async, followed with a 'hook-style' pattern which does useState and useEffect to make the async results available to your UI. There is no chance on earth that this code will run as I don't have access to your environment to really try it, but it gives you an idea of how it might be refactored. If the state needs to be consumed by multiple parts of your UI, then makes sense for the useMappedLocation hook to assign a mappedLocation variable in an ancestor component, with the result passed down to descendants through Context, Composition or Props. This will have the effect of caching the result.

I've also sketched out how a second hook might consume the first hook as I think having re-read your question that was the point you got stuck with your original approach. However, embedding the useMappedLocation hook in multiple places will cause it to be re-executed multiple times and will not benefit from caching compared to hoisting it into an ancestor component.

```
const apikey = "myapikey";

interface GeoEntry {
  address_components:[
    {types:("country"|"administrative_area_level_1")[]
      short_name:string,
      long_name:string
    }
  ]
}

interface MappedLocation {
  state:string,
  country:string
}

async function getLocation(){
  return await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
}

async function getFirstGeoEntry() : Promise<GeoEntry>{
  const {latitude,longitude} = await getLocation();
  const response = await fetch(
          "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
            latitude +
            "," +
            longitude +
            "&key=" +
            apikey
        )
  const json = await response.json();
  return json.results[0]
}

function getStateNameLong(geoEntry:GeoEntry){
  return geoEntry.address_components.filter(
              (x: any) =>
                x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "administrative_area_level_1")
                  .length > 0
            )[0].long_name
}

function getCountryNameShort(geoEntry:GeoEntry){
  return geoEntry.address_components.filter(
              (x: any) => x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "country").length > 0
            )[0].short_name
} 

async function getMappedLocation() : Promise<MappedLocation>{
  const geoEntry = await getFirstGeoEntry();
  return {
    country:getCountryNameShort(geoEntry),
    state:getStateNameLong(geoEntry),
  }
}

const useMappedLocation = () => {
  const [mappedLocation,setMappedLocation] = useState<MappedLocation>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setMappedLocation(await getMappedLocation())
    })()
  }, [])
  return mappedLocation
}
```

Here's how a second hook ( useCountryData ) might consume the first ( useMappedLocation ). Note the useEffect handles the case that the location hasn't arrived yet, and mappedLocation is in the dependency array to ensure the useEffect runs a second time when the mappedLocation DOES finally arrive.

```
import { useMappedLocation } from './useMappedLocation';

export const useCountryData = () => {
  const [earliest2, setEarliest2] = useState([]);
  const [countryDeaths, setcountryDeaths] = useState(Number);
  const [countryCases, setcountryCases] = useState(Number);

  const mappedLocation = useMappedLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    if(mappedLocation !== null){
      axios.get("https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries")
        .then((response) => {
          setEarliest2(response.data);

          const countryArray = response.data.filter(
            (item) => item.country === mappedLocation.country
          );

          const resCountryDeaths = countryArray[0].deaths;
          setcountryDeaths(resCountryDeaths);

          const resCountryCases = countryArray[0].cases;
          setcountryCases(resCountryCases);
          console.log("hiiii", countryCases);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }, [mappedLocation]);

  return { countryCases, countryDeaths };
};
```

Comment: Updated to add how a second hook consumes the first.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your time for this. I didn't realize my code patterns were incorrectly used, you cleaned up my code a lot. I just have one issue - Whenever I load up the app for the first time without access to location, the location names on the front-end don't load up. I have to save my project, and then they will load after about a minute. But, when I load up the app a second time, it's fine. How can I fix this? I have also updated my code for you to better understand my answer. Do I need to use useEffect for this to handle this case for it to run a second time?

Comment: In the code I shared the useEffect which delivers useMappedLocation() will only run once ( see https://dev.to/rozenmd/understanding-useeffect-the-dependency-array-obg ). Nothing triggers a retry if it fails the first time. It remains unset. So the question is - what should retry behaviour be if getMappedLocation throws in the useEffect()?  Short-cut approaches include: keep retrying periodically, or keep retrying periodically until mappedLocation has a value and then stop. If you have moved your code forward, perhaps you could ask this different question with a reference of the latest code.

Comment: To give you a clue how to progress with async retry see https://tsplay.dev/w629Rw which outlines how you use a While loop in async to keep retrying with a delay.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look into this.

Comment: Coming back to this, I'd like to add a function that checks whether the user has location services enabled for this app, mostly to check if they denied permissions. In expo docs, `Location.hasServicesEnabledSync()` checks whether or not the location services are enabled. I want to make it so if they deny permission, it returns a JSX component saying that location services are off. How can I add this into the current code?

Comment: I would make it that getLocation() throws an Error. That could be added to a catch clause within the async function embedded in useMappedLocation(). When you catch the propagated error you need to decide how you will make that visible to the caller (e.g. a special value of mappedLocation). Can you use maybe the strict value `false` ? That's then a const value inline in your render function so you can use it for control flow - serving the component with a special view instead. It'll only eventually settle with a `false` value though so you'll have an intermediate `null` state to handle too.

Comment: The `Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync()` returns 'true` if location services are enabled, or `false` if not. I was thinking this would a more convenient way of handling this. Would your example work better? Could you also give an example of your response in your code sample?

Comment: That's not a way of handling the failure, that's a way of checking for the failure. The question of handling it when you're attempting to create a simple useMappedLocation() hook is a separate question. My comment proposed how to pass the 'failure' status of the location call through all the async layers of the hook. It's how a hook caller can find out, using a 'standard' interface, there's no mapped location. There may be lots of good ways of _checking_ for failure, but I'm proposing an EAFP rather than LBYL strategy to _notify_ any failure to avoid TOCTTOU bugs in this class of logic.